# How can I write my optimization problem as a SDP problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, maximum-likelihood, semidefinite-programming

I have the following maximum likelihood optimization problem:

$$
\hat{X}=\underset{X}{\text{argmax}} \left ( T_{1}X^{T}GX+T_{2}X^{T}Y  \right ) \\
\text{s.t.} \left\{\begin{matrix} 
X\in \{\pm 1\}^{n}\\
X^{T} \mathbf{1}=0\\ 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
where $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are constants, $Y \in\{\pm 1\}^{n}$ is a known $n\times 1$ vector, $G$ is a known $n\times n$ matrix and $X$ is a $n\times 1$ vector.

I am going to write this problem as a semi-definite programming problem. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: This is a binary quadratic problem. Do you mean you want to make an SDP relaxation?

Comment: yes, we can consider its convex relaxation similar to the SDP relaxation. Do you know how can we make a semi-definite program?

Comment: Try (6.38), (6.39), (6.40) here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html#relaxations-of-boolean-optimization